# gtkmm + cmake (windows)

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, gtkmm3

Приветствую дамы и господа. Не могу автоматически "зацепить" директорию gtkmm с помощью CMake. [CMakeList](https://gist.github.com/continue98/1bcf722d1d6e55666a6353a4cd73289e), [CMake выводит, что gtkmm не найден (хотя gtkmm на C:/)](https://gist.github.com/continue98/97b56aab7bc777649b7997386219e346) и соответственно переменные пусты. В чем проблема и как ее решить?

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день!

Проблема может быть в нескольких местах:

1. Зависимости `gtkmm3`(например `gtk-3`) не установлены
2. Отсутствует `PkgConfig` файл, указывающий где можно найти `gtkmm3`
3. Переменная окружения(не windows, а POSIX окружения) `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` не охватывает директорию файла `gtkmm-3.0.pc`

---

Было бы прекрасно увидеть Ваш вывод команды

`pkg-config --list-all | grep -i gtk`

, чтобы понимать куда двигаться дальше

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNyt0.png

Comment: Ваше окружение просто ничего не видит.
Попробуйте по установить по оригинальной инструкции от Gnome-сообщества: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/MSWindows

По этой инструкции очень удобно установить всё(включая зависимости, сам pkg-config и его файлы для gtkmm)

Comment: pkg-config я устанавливал вручную. pacman нет в msys. Может есть ещё какие то предложения?

Comment: Но зато ведь в MSYS2 он есть, да и установка оного лишь запуск инсталлятора. Попробуйте всё же этот вариант, он предполагает меньшее количество действий, тем более ручных, если не считать вводов команды pacman'у :)

Comment: поставил, но толку ноль. все так же не находит.

Comment: установили MSYS2, и при помощи pacman компилятор, и пакет gtkmm под Вашу архитектуру?

Очень странно. Покажите вывод команды pkg-config --list-all.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/continue98/a77cad4bab13b0c01d44b0cc0cc7b643

Comment: времени не так много. по этому спрошу: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tview/files/gtkmm_bin_3_6.7z/download

Тогда как вручную указать пути до gtkmm?